# Help on eval() function

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, eval

I need help on this `eval()` problem:

```
var ScoreFuncName = 'scoreCondition_' + criteriaName;

var allCheckBox = $('div#'+SubListId).find("input:image[name^='" + ChkBoxPrefix + "'][value='1']");

eval(ScoreFuncName + '(' + allCheckBox.length + ')');
```

The `eval()` function is evaluating which checkbox is ticked and will do other things accordingly, it worked great in Firefox but not in google Chrome and IE.

Scratching my head for 3 days on how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? Why is it necessary to use eval for this?And why is that selector looking for an 'value=1' on an image tag??

Comment: This is not a proper use of eval.

Comment: I assume `ScoreFuncName` is a variable assigned with the name of a function that is defined elsewhere? How about you show the code for that function? And then, delete the `eval()` and do it properly by just calling the function directly as `window[ScoreFuncName](allCheckBox.length);`

Answer (score 6):

You should not be using eval for that.

If the function is in global scope. All you need to do is

```
window[ScoreFuncName](allCheckBox.length);
```

It would be better to name space it instead of using a global with window

Answer (score 2):

Eval is not needed to do this. Also take notice that I am calling `size` on the jQuery object rather than `length`.

```
var scoreFunc = this['scoreCondition_' + criteriaName];

var allCheckBox = 
    $('div#'+SubListId).find("input:image[name^='" + ChkBoxPrefix + "'][value='1']");

scoreFunc(allCheckBox.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm... don't.

There realistically is not a need to use eval in this condition (and I would say that there is no need for a string look-up of the function). Since it looks clear that you have a finite and knowable number of conditions and a finite and knowable number of functions, then you can simply use a switch to actually select a function dynamically:

```
var toRun; // variable to store the function.
switch(criteriaName)
{
    case "criteria1":
       // keep the actual function in the variable, not some string.
       toRun = function(e){console.log("I is so special! " + e)}
       break;
    case "criteria2":
       toRun = function(e){console.log( e + " is not a squid!" )}     
       break;
}
var allCheckBox = $('div#'+SubListId).find("input:image[name^='" + 
                     ChkBoxPrefix + "'][value='1']"); 
// then just call it!
toRun(allCheckBox.length)
```